# How to get the index of dynamically created multiple panels in C# GUI form,when a checkbox is clicked in one of the dynamically created panel

Tags: c#

I have a split container panel in GUI Form.When a button is clicked in left panel,it pulls out information along with multiple checkboxes on dynamically created panels on the right panel using a loop.Each panel on the right side can have multiple checkboxes based on some condition.For example, the first panel has one checkbox and the second panel below the first has got 8 checkboxes in the same row.When  one of the checkboxes in second panel is clicked, I have to get the index of the that panel to do some manipulation. Tab index does not help me to get one as each panel can have any number of checkboxes.I spent a day to get around the problem with no luck. Your help will be much appreciated. I have posted the code below.

```
      for (int j = 0; j < numOfSensors.Count; j++)
         {

                sensorpanel = new Panel();
                sensorpanel.Size = new Size(800, 60);
                sensorpanel.Location = new Point(0, Y);
                sensorpanel.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                sensorpanel.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel_Paint);

                Button sensor = new Button();
                sensor.Size = new Size(200, 50);
                sensor.Location = new Point(1, 1);
                sensor.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                sensor.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.LightGray;
                String sensorType = "Occupancy";
                sensor.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                sensor.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                sensor.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                 sensorpanel.Controls.Add(sensor);

                if (sensorType.Equals("Occupancy")) 
                {
                    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                    cb.Location = new Point(380, 15);
                    cb.Size = new Size(20, 17);
                    cb.Checked = checkBox(j,0);
                    cb.Text = "Occupancy";
                    checksensorbuttons.Add(cb);
                    cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cb_CheckChanged);
                    sensorpanel.Controls.Add(cb);

                }
                else if (sensorType.Equals("Multi-input:Digital"))
                {
                    int xLoc = 210;
                    int yLoc = 15;

                    for (int k = 16; k <32; k+=2)
                    {
                        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                        cb.Location = new Point(xLoc, yLoc);
                        cb.Size = new Size(20, 17);
                        cb.Checked = checkBox(j,k);
                        cb.Text = "Multi-input";

                        cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cb_CheckChanged);
                        sensorpanel.Controls.Add(cb);
                        xLoc += 30;
                    }
                   splitContainer.panel2.Controls.Add(sensorpanel);

                }
```

//checkedchanged eventhandler

```
       private void cb_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;

        if (checkbox.Text.Equals("Occupancy"))
        {

           // How to get the index of the panel when a checkbox in corresponding panel is checked?
            if (checkbox.Checked == true)
            {

                //some manipulation
            }
            else
            {
                //some manipulation
            }
        }
        else if (checkbox.Text.Equals("Multi-input"))
        {

            //get index of the panel where one of the checkboxes are clicked
            if (checkbox.Checked == true)
            {

               //do some manipulation
            }
            else
            {
                //do some manipulation
            }


        }
```

Comment: The "CheckBox.Parent" provides the Panel. If you need the PanelIndex, Use the "Tag" property of the CheckBoxes (or that of the Panel) to store the Panel index.

Comment: Fixed it using tag property.Thanks Graffito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways

1. Use `Name` property of the `checkbox`. When the `checkbox` is created assign it a logical name which makes it easier to identify it. Only `string` can be used here.
2. Use `Tag` property of the `checkbox` to preserve the data you want to refer it. Its good place to store any `object` and not just `string`.
3. Use Parent property of the checkbox to access checkbox's parent properties.

As a best practice, assign a logical name to the dynamic controls. This is the best way to identify the control.

```
sensorpanel.Name = "panel" + j.ToString();
this.Controls.Add(sensorpanel);

:
:
cb.Text = "Occupancy";
cb.Tag = "panel Index = " + j.ToString();
cb.Name = "panel" + j.ToString() + "_" + "cb_" + cb.Text;
sensorpanel.Controls.Add(cb);


void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
    string mssg;
    mssg = "Name = " + checkbox.Name;
    mssg = "tag = " + checkbox.Tag;
    mssg = "Parent text = " + checkbox.Parent.Text;
    mssg = "Parent name = " + checkbox.Parent.Name;
    MessageBox.Show(mssg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mukul.  I wasn't quite sure about the tag property use before. Thanks again for your elaborated answer.Fixed it !